# Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral, I want to know two solutions.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

$$\int _0^1 x^2 dx=\frac{1}{3}x^2 \bigg|_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{3}$$
This solution is the Riemann integral. (strictly speaking, fundamental theorem of calculus)

I want to solve with the Lebesgue integral instead of the Riemann integral.

So,

$$\int _I x^2 d\mu(x), \quad I=[0,1],\quad \mu: Lebesgue\, measure(i.e.\, \mu(I)=1).$$

sol) Let us decompose a given closed interval $I=[0,1]$ of y-axis into n subintervals

$\displaystyle y_1=\frac{1}{n}, y_2=\frac{2}{n}, \dots, y_n=\frac{n}{n}, $

To find each measure, so $\displaystyle f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt x$,

$\displaystyle A_1=f^{-1}\left ([0,\frac{1}{n}]\right), A_2=f^{-1}\left ([\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}]\right), \dots, A_n=f^{-1}\left ([\frac{n-1}{n},\frac{n}{n}]\right)$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y_i \mu(A_i)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left\{\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\sqrt\frac{1}{n}\bigg)+\frac{2}{n}\bigg(\sqrt\frac{2}{n}-\sqrt\frac{1}{n}\bigg)+\frac{3}{n}\bigg(\sqrt\frac{3}{n}-\sqrt\frac{2}{n}\bigg)+\cdots+\frac{n}{n}\bigg(\sqrt\frac{n}{n}-\sqrt\frac{n-1}{n}\bigg)\right\}$$

$$=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left\{\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}\bigg(n\sqrt{n}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\sqrt{k}}\bigg)\right\}$$
$$=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left\{ 1-\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\sqrt{k}}}{n\sqrt n}\right\}=\frac{1}{3} \qquad (\because)\, Taylor\,expansion$$

<Question.>

Is it correct to solve the Lebesgue integral like this?
Or am I misunderstanding the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: You're effectively still using a Riemann sum to compute the integral, whereas the definition of Lebesgue integrals involves approximating the integrand with simple functions and taking supremum over *all* simple functions.

Comment: Thanks you for answer. What I want to know is the problem of trying to approach the Lebesgue integral(measure) from the Bergman function in an easier way. Is the above solution correct?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem for calculation